# CSS modules the exported module is an empty object?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript

I use typescript and `create-react-app` to create projects and added `typings-for-css-modules-loader` and opened `css-modules`.

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  use: [
    require.resolve('style-loader'),
    {
      loader: require.resolve('typings-for-css-modules-loader'),
      options: {
        modules: true,
        namedExport: true,
        camelCase: true,
      },
    },
    {
      loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
      options: {
        // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
        // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
        ident: 'postcss',
        plugins: () => [
          require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
          autoprefixer({
            browsers: [
              '>1%',
              'last 4 versions',
              'Firefox ESR',
              'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
            ],
            flexbox: 'no-2009',
          }),
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
},
```

I added the `*.css.d.ts` file

```
export const wrapper: string;
```

[image]

`css-modules` still exports empty objects

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as Styles from './LogIn.css';
import * as ReactTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group';
import { Form, Icon, Input, Button } from 'antd';

console.log(Styles) // {}
console.log(Styles.wrapper) // undefined
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

react-app-rewired and yarn eject are contradictory

use typescript and css modules

```
{
            test: /\.css$/,
            include: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
                options: {
                  importLoaders: 1
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            test: /\.css$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
              require.resolve('style-loader'),
              {
                loader: require.resolve('typings-for-css-modules-loader'),
                options: {
                  modules: true,
                  namedExport: true,
                  camelCase: true
                },
              },
              {
                loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
                options: {
                  // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
                  // https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/2677
                  ident: 'postcss',
                  plugins: () => [
                    require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
                    autoprefixer({
                      browsers: [
                        '>1%',
                        'last 4 versions',
                        'Firefox ESR',
                        'not ie < 9', // React doesn't support IE8 anyway
                      ],
                      flexbox: 'no-2009',
                    }),
                  ],
                },
              },
            ],
          },
```